# RichTextbox line validations with empty lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, richtextbox, rtf

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
<<Empty line>>
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
<<Empty line>>
<<Empty line>>
```

I have a rich text box to display 10 lines, however the data in the database has more than 10 lines for ex.

> I need to remove empty lines greater than 10 and perserve any empty
>   line that are in between 10?

so that the expected result should be

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
<<Empty line>>
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10

String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBoxr.Lines[Count]) => This if i use, it detects out the last line(in this example 12) and keeps the 11th empty line, which i don't want. Any help?
```

Comment: You do know index is 0 based?

Answer (score 0):

Apply a TRIM in your query or your RichTextbox.Text to get rid of trailing white space.

Answer (score 0):

Technically there is no 11th line. What is happening is the tenth line ends with a newline.  Get rid of that ending newline using String.Trim on the result.

```
char[] charsToTrim = {'\r', '\n'};
s = s.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
```

...Or something like that.